# Squid or Varnish for Django?

Tags: django, varnish, squid

I have a django application that needs to be built to scale in the future. I am considering http caching & ESI for the solution. Has any of you any experience with either Squid or Varnish? What works better with Django? I just want the caching & ESI functionality. We are using NGINX as the reverse proxy.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think you need varnish? Maybe it's not necessary. Take a look at the cache_page decorator (or more advanced django plugins like https://github.com/twidi/django-adv-cache-tag) in combination with memcached.

Comment: Disqus gets something like 5 billion hits a month running Django using Varnish.  At this point is the app even getting that type of attention?  I would worry about scaling later since Django is proven to scale with sites like Instagram, Pinterest, Mozilla, Disqus etc...